# Problem with MonoTouch CorePlot binding

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-plot

I have tried to get the Core-Plot library to work with MonoTouch but without any luck. When I try to run the sample from the CorePlot binding at GitHub ([link](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/CorePlot)) in the simulator I only get a "mtouch failed with no output (1)" error. I have the latest MonoTouch alpha (3.99.13.9917).

Has anyone managed to run the sample? Or are there other MonoTouch projects using CorePlot available that I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in MonoTouch 3.99.13 with simulator projects that required native compilation.  This is fixed in the next release.  You can work on device in the interim.